# Write ef core statement that preform count on SQL

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

Why does .net core 2.2. ef this

```
 var posBlagajnik = rampa.Doc.Where(x => x.SmjenaId == smjena.Id && (x.DocTipNavigation.IsRacun || x.DocTipNavigation.IsStorno)).GroupBy(x => x.User.ImeIprezime)
            .Select(x => new PosBlagajnik() { ime = x.Key, brojRacuna = x.Count(), inkas = x.Sum(f => f.Iznos.Value) }).ToList();
```

Preform in memory but not in SQL.
My context warning me

> The LINQ expression '"Count()"' could not be translated and will be
>   evaluated locally.

I want to send to SQL something like this.

```
select
                    AspNetUsers.ImeIprezime
                    ,COUNt(*) as brojRacuna
                    ,sum(iznos) as inkas
                from doc
                inner join AspNetUsers on doc.user_id=AspNetUsers.id
                inner join dokumenti on doc.doc_tip=dokumenti.id
                where doc.smjena_id=79 and (dokumenti.isRacun = 1 or dokumenti.isStorno=1)

                group by  AspNetUsers.ImeIprezime
```

### Edit after comments

Thanks to @IvanStoev help, I did manage to write ef that prefom sql aggregates.

Here is new question accoring research

When I changed my ef query to

```
var posBlagajnik = rampa.Doc
                    .Where(x => x.SmjenaId == smjena.Id && (x.DocTipNavigation.IsRacun || x.DocTipNavigation.IsStorno))
                    .GroupBy(x => x.User.ImeIprezime)
                    .Select(x => new PosBlagajnik() { ime = x.Key, brojRacuna = x.Count(),
                        inkas = x.Sum(f => f.Iznos) 
                    }).ToList();
```

Ef start performing sql aggregation.

Initial I used `x.Sum(f => f.Iznos.Value)` because f.Iznos is Nullable (decimal?), and **inkas** on **PosBlagajnik** was non Nullable . By using .Value I did convert decima? to decimal.
Looks like that confuses ef to preform locally all query.

Is this normally behove of ef or it is some kind of bug ?

Comment: Hi, can you show the whole query? I suspect there is some `GroupBy` operation involved, because it it's just a simple table (DbSet) query, it will work.

Comment: @IvanStoev my appolgies, this does preform SQL i have other ef Ill edit my question as soon as posibile

Comment: @IvanStoev sory once again, I did edit my question including original ef statement and new tsql I am trying to send to SQL

Comment: No problem. But even with the last update it should translate to SQL. What is `f.Iznos`? Nullable type? What if you select just the `x.Count()` (comment out `, inkas = x.Sum(f => f.Iznos.Value)`)?

Comment: @IvanStoev f.Iznos is decimal? , Looks like when I did not include .Value in x.Sum() ef does preform SQL group. I did use .Value becuse my other model PosBlagajnik was non nullabile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is actually the expression

```
x.Sum(f => f.Iznos.Value)
```

Currently EF Core translates to SQL only aggregate methods with simple property access selectors.

The issue can be solved by using `??` operator *outside* the aggregate function:

```
x.Sum(f => f.Iznos) ?? 0
```